Word TOC format. Need Bold section number and title and not bold leading and page number
In MS Word, the TOC modify option for TOC 1,2,3...appears to join the formatting for these features together: Chapter number, chapter/section heading, leading (the dots between the heading and the page number) and the page number itself. My new style guide as demanding bold chapter number and heading and unbold leading and page number. Is there any way to set this up in a custom TOC, or will I have to manually redo every time I regenerate the TOC?

Remove Bold from your heading styles and apply it directly to the heading text making it bold.
The Table of Contents (TOC) styles which generally control how your TOC looks control the entire entry or line in the TOC.
The built-in Heading styles in Word are generally Bold, but formatting that is part of the paragraph style for text incorporated into a TOC is usually brought along to the TOC.
So, you want your TOC style to have the formatting you want for the dot leader and page number.
However, if formatting is directly applied to the text that is used to create the TOC that formatting will be carried into the Table of Contents.
See TOC Tips and Tricks by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill for more on this.
For more about special properties of the built-in heading styles, see Why Use Built-In Heading Styles by Shauna Kelly.
